# Any good SVN tool for eclipse to manage multiple repositories at once?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, multiple-repositories

I'm using subclipse for svn in eclipse, however it can't manage multiple repositories, I had to disconnect and connect again, disconnect and connect again to transfer different revisions of my application. The result now is that I've lost my latest revision and I'm stuck with this old revision and there are projects inside projects, etc, etc. It's all a mess. I need some kind of tool which would manage multiple repositories and would allow you to choose which repository to commit to...

Any solutions to this? I need a better tool for SVN...

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're having to do? The Subversion client in Eclipse doesn't manage repositories, it manages working copies. You shouldn't be "connecting and disconnecting" - possibly *switching*. You can work with multiple projects checked out from the repository at once with Eclipse, even checking out twice from the same URL to different working copies locally. If you're actually maintaining the same project in multiple **repositories**, you've got a huge mess ahead of you.

Comment: Yeah, exactly but if you don't want to spam the official repository with your own draft copies, then it's more comfortable to have different repositories, at least for me. And yes, it messed up completely, I hope I'll puck up some good practices from this experience, cause right now my project isn't working and I can't find my latest revision.

Comment: Create a private branch to work on the code in isolation. Then you can merge your changes back in with everyone else when they're ready. Or check out a DVCS like git or hg. But putting a single project into multiple repositories like you describe is just a big bag o' hurt.

Comment: @alroc Yeah, you're right about that, it is a big bag o' hurt, but in my case, I don't want to spam the repository with useless commit comments and I don't want my history to be seen by other people except for me. I mean those are changes that are not necessary sometimes and are just random backups to not mess up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using SVN as a separate tool outside of Eclipse. It is not the most elegant approach, but gives you more control over what you do.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized, this might be a really good way for me! This way I wouldn't mess up my project in Eclipse and will keep the copies that I want in the official repository since there aren't so many!